# Can i use ANGULAR1 modules in ANGULAR2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have did so many projects in AngularJS,  Now world moving fast in html5 and javascript engine technology.

And angular team also behind the development of angular2, But right now there are lots of angular modules present in web.

So my question is these modules must be rewrite in Angular2 or there any black window to use [angular1](https://angularjs.org/) modules in [angular2](http://angular2.com/).

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS 2 is not backwards compatible with AngularJS 1.

On their [blog](http://angularjs.blogspot.be/2014/10/ng-europe-angular-13-and-beyond.html), the Angular team wrote:

> Our goal with Angular 2 is to make the best possible set of tools for
>   building web apps not constrained by maintaining backwards
>   compatibility with existing APIs. Once we have an initial version of
>   Angular 2, we'll start to work on a migration path for Angular 1 apps.

So, there will be no backwards compatibility and your existing apps and modules won't run, but there will be help to migrate your code to version 2; this could be in the form of migration tools or step-by-step guides.